# How to put a tooltip on a grid-ui select filter

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

In ui-grid, does anyone know how to create a tooltip that will show on the options of a select filter?  For example, in the [filter example tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering), to have a tooltip show when you hover on the 'male', 'female',... options?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to override the template for ui-grid/ui-grid-filter is ok.

```
    $templateCache.put('ui-grid/ui-grid-filter',
    "<div class=\"ui-grid-filter-container\" ng-style=\"col.extraStyle\" ng-repeat=\"colFilter in col.filters\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-filter-cancel-button-hidden' : colFilter.disableCancelFilterButton === true }\"><div ng-if=\"colFilter.type !== 'select'\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"ui-grid-filter-input ui-grid-filter-input-{{$index}}\" ng-model=\"colFilter.term\" ng-attr-placeholder=\"{{colFilter.placeholder || ''}}\" aria-label=\"{{colFilter.ariaLabel || aria.defaultFilterLabel}}\"><div role=\"button\" class=\"ui-grid-filter-button\" ng-click=\"removeFilter(colFilter, $index)\" ng-if=\"!colFilter.disableCancelFilterButton\" ng-disabled=\"colFilter.term === undefined || colFilter.term === null || colFilter.term === ''\" ng-show=\"colFilter.term !== undefined && colFilter.term !== null && colFilter.term !== ''\"><i class=\"ui-grid-icon-cancel\" ui-grid-one-bind-aria-label=\"aria.removeFilter\">&nbsp;</i></div></div><div ng-if=\"colFilter.type === 'select'\"><select ng-model=\"colFilter.term\" ng-show=\"colFilter.selectOptions.length > 0\" ng-attr-placeholder=\"{{colFilter.placeholder || aria.defaultFilterLabel}}\" aria-label=\"{{colFilter.ariaLabel || ''}}\" class=\"ui-grid-filter-select ui-grid-filter-input-{{$index}}\">    <option ng-repeat=\"option in colFilter.selectOptions\" value=\"{{ option.value }}\" title=\"{{ option.label }}\">{{ option.label }}</option></select><div role=\"button\" class=\"ui-grid-filter-button-select\" ng-click=\"removeFilter(colFilter, $index)\" ng-if=\"!colFilter.disableCancelFilterButton\" ng-disabled=\"colFilter.term === undefined || colFilter.term === null || colFilter.term === ''\" ng-show=\"colFilter.term !== undefined && colFilter.term != null\"><i class=\"ui-grid-icon-cancel\" ui-grid-one-bind-aria-label=\"aria.removeFilter\">&nbsp;</i></div></div></div>");
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5JHQAscKUoaGJW44sfjM?p=preview)

http://plnkr.co/edit/5JHQAscKUoaGJW44sfjM?p=preview

Comment: Hi @Fiddler99, does it answer your question?